# Best approach for download asynchronous data from webservice and store in core data

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data, asynchronous

I'm currently working on app with core data. There are 80 tables in the model. I am taking data through web service. 
Current approach in single web service response get update from server, with the that response make request to server. There are 70 request hit to server.
With current approach pull data using

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];
```

After each response, compare new data with old data from store. save only updated data.
Now i want to do it asynchronous download data and store response in the core data.
For pull data asynchronous I want to use

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest*) request
                      queue:(NSOperationQueue*) queue
          completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* connectionError)) handler ;
```

What will be best way to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking is best approach for download asynchronous data from webservice and store in core data...